# Generate PDF containing Images and Text

Tags: asp.net, pdf-generation, itext

I want to generate a pdf using iTextSharp from my ASP.NET Web Forms application containing a table with 2 columns and as many rows required and image and text in them. But currently, I can add either an image or text not both in one cell. Below is a HTML markup example of my desired format:

```
<table align="center" style="border-spacing:20px;">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label style="display:block;text-align:center;">Corvette</label>
            <br />
            <img src="QrCodes/Ibrahim.jpg" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <label style="display:block;text-align:center;">Mercedes</label>
            <br />
            <img src="QrCodes/Amazon.jpg" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

How can I create this format from my code behind? It can be from HTML string or using iTextSharp object. Whichever gets it working. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Current code:

```
PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create));
doc.Open();
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(Server.MapPath(@item.ItemQrCode));
iTextSharp.text.Image pdfImage = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(image, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
pdfImage.Alignment = iTextSharp.text.Image.UNDERLYING;

Phrase phrase = new Phrase(item.ItemName);
PdfPCell cellText = new PdfPCell(phrase);
cellText.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
cellText.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;

PdfPCell cellImage = new PdfPCell(pdfImage);
cellImage.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
cellImage.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;

table.AddCell(cellImage);

doc.Add(table);
doc.Close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there were 2 columns in the main table, when I added cells it added them side by side. But my solution was to take tables with 1 column for each cell and then add them to the main table cell to get text followed by image below it. Code:

```
PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create));
doc.Open();
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);

System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(Server.MapPath(@item.ItemQrCode));
iTextSharp.text.Image pdfImage = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(image, ImageFormat.Jpeg);

PdfPTable cellTable = new PdfPTable(1); //Table for each cell

Phrase phrase = new Phrase(item.ItemName);
PdfPCell cellText = new PdfPCell(phrase);
cellText.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
cellText.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;

PdfPCell cellImage = new PdfPCell(pdfImage);
cellImage.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
cellImage.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;

cellTable.AddCell(cellText);
table.AddCell(cellImage);

table.AddCell(cellTable); //Add each cells' table to main table cell

doc.Add(table);
doc.Close();
```